# How to make server ArrayList accessible by multiple clients?

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I have a simple arraylist and made a few methods in my server to add print edit or remove things from it, it works fine if I just have my server up and connect to it with my client at that port number.

But if I open another client and connect to it, and add an element from my first client onto the arraylist, it acts like the arraylist is still empty on the second one. How do I make it so the arraylist can be accessed by both of these? if I add a new item to my arraylist from client 1 then when I print the arraylist in client 2 I want to be able to see that item.

Some extra details: 
I'm using Collections.synchronizedList and a thread for each client, and the methods that add, print, remove, etc things from the arraylist has "public synchronized void " if that matters at all.

ArrayList initialization:

```
public List<Data> database = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Data>());
```

Comment: Share some code!

Comment: I think you are using some sort of instance wide variable when you want to use class wide variable. Still, need to see some code.

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of my code would be relevant? I added the ArrayList initialization and my client class

Comment: Where is the part you are using `database` and the part you are creating instances of `Clients`?

Comment: creating clients is in the main method which I just added, now that I see it maybe it has something to do with the "Clients c = new Server().new Clients(connection);"?

Comment: Where is the part you are using `database`?

Comment: so run() in the Clients class takes in the client request and depending on what it is it will call one of the 4 synchronized void methods, which operate on the list, the problem is when they are called and changes are made, its only applied for this specific client, other clients cant see the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using instance scope. Use class wide scope and things should work. Just add the key work `static` to database declaration:

```
public static List<Data> database = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Data>());
```

Comment: It seems that was the issue, it works now for multiple clients! god bless you, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

So right now it seems like each of your clients have their own instance of your ArrayList. You could workaround this by making it application-wide (like static) but I'm guessing you would want to save the results after the program stops. Easy way about this would be saving the results to a file, so lets say on "get" you load the list, on "submit" you load the current list and save changes and so on. I would however recommend getting familiar with SQL Databases.